# Paginar consulta con Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente controlador:

Necesito que al final mandarle a la vista las facturas pero paginadas osea de a 20...

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {                   

        //se trae la informacion de la base de datos y/o modelo
        var facturas = db.VwFacturasGeneralFull;         

        //por defecto el siguiente switch va ornedar por el sigueinte:
        var facturasOrdenadas = facturas.OrderBy(f => f.IDFactura).ToList();


      return View(facturasOrdenadas.ToList());
    }
```

Lo he intentado de varias formas pero no lo logro.

Answer (score 1):

para realizar la paginación debes usar los métodos [Skip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb357513(v=vs.110).aspx) y [Take()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300906%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) según te muestro en el siguiente ejemplo

```
int numberOfObjectsPerPage = 20;
int pageNumber = 1;

var queryResultPage = queryResult
                          .Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * pageNumber)
                          .Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage);
```

Te dejo un enlace de un artículo (en inglés) que puede serte de utilidad [Return Or Skip Elements in a Sequence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/return-or-skip-elements-in-a-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es coger un cierto rango de valores de la lista en tu caso los 20 primeros valores puedes usar algo así:

```
 var listaADevolver =facturasOrdenadas.GetRange(0, 20);
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.